# Creating functions to read file in python

Tags: python, function

This a sample txt file called "price_file.txt":

```
Apple,$2.55
Banana,$5.79
Carrot,$8.19
Dragon Fruit,$8.24
Eggs,$1.44
Hamburger Buns,$1.89
Ice Pops,$4.42
```

This is a function to allow the user to read the file:

```
def addpricefile (price_file):  
           # input: price file txt 
           # output: item mapped to its price in a dictionary  
            global item_to_price 
            for next_line in price_file: 
                            item,price = next_line.strip().split(',')
                            item_to_price[item]= float(price[1:]) #map item to price
            return item_to_price    
    
    p = input ("Enter price file: ")
    price_file2 = open(p, "r")
    price_file = price_file2.readlines()
    for next_line in price_file: 
            addpricefile(price_file2)  
    print(item_to_price)
    price_file2.close()
```

However, I get an empty dictionary as the output. How do I fix this?

Comment: the problem here is that you are reading the whole file contents into the variable "price_file", and then passing the file, with the read pointer located at the file and, to the function in the call `addpricefile(price_file2)`. 
You are trying and retrying things there - just do not retry: do it. There are no need for 2 "for" loops in this task, nor for reading the lines previously.

Comment: on a separate note: it is hard to read/write python code formatted like this - try to use 4 spaces for identation level - and check the tooling you are using and configure it to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, I was a bit confused by what you had there but you can simplify the operation a bit. This will achieve the same result. I hope this helps you solve your problem.

```
def openAndSeperate(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as file:
        priceList = {}
        for i in file:
            i = i.strip('\n').split(',')
            priceList[i[0]] = float(str(i[1])[1:])
        return priceList


def main():
    filename = 'price_file.txt'#input('Enter File Name: \n')
    priceList = openAndSeperate(filename)
    print(priceList)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```